# How I can get information from a tag in HTML WebView?

Tags: android, html, webview

I would like to know how I can get a information inside a tag in HTML. I don't know if I am doing it right because It don't return any information. I show you my android code to see if you can help me.

code class:

```
    public class WebView1 extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */   
WebView browse;         
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)      {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.webview1);
         browse = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);                     

         browse.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

         browse.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override  
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    File input = new File("file:///android_asset/ejemploWebview.html");
                    Document doc = null;
                    try {
                        doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url
                    //Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get();

                    Element content = doc.getElementById("div");
                    Elements links = content.getElementsByTag("id");
                    String linkId = links.attr("manolo");
                    System.out.print(linkId); //I need that it return Hiiii!
                    }
            });     } }
```

code HTML:

```
 <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <div id="james">hellooo!</div>
    <div id="paco">byeee!</div>
    <div id="manolo">Hiii!</div>
    </html>
```

I hope I explained correctly! 
Thank's you! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I've always had better results from JSoup when using the selectors, as detailed [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).

From the example you give, it appears you want to retrieve the div values by their ID, you can use this :

> el#id: elements with ID, e.g. div#logo

So either use 3 occurrences of the above, or just select the divs and iterate over them doing whatever you need to do.

Hope this helps.

P.S, easiest thing I found was to put a breakpoint after you call `doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");`, then use your IDEs' expression builder to work out which selector does what you want :)